# Make OS X El Capitan announce time only when screen is unlocked or during night time

Tags: macos, accessibility, time

I use the incredibly useful feature on OS X to announce time on the hour for my time management by checking the option in Date & Time preferences.

[image: OS X Date & Time]

However, the time announcements keep going on during the night unless I shutdown my iMac (which I don't want to). Is there a way to silence it during night time or to make it not announce time when the screen is locked?

I know there was a [related question for OS X Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43057/how-can-i-set-quiet-hours-for-os-x-time-announcements) but posting this to see if there is a better/different solution for El Capitan.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have 'Do Not Distrub' mode set on?
Go to System Preferences -> Notifications and set up as needed.

[image]